# How to schedule an autoupdate for my external subcharts (Bitnami)

Tags: kubernetes, dependencies, dependency-management, bitnami

I would like to schedule an autoupdate that checks if there is a newer version for my subcharts.
In my case I'm using Kafka from Bitnami.

How can I make a process that checks my Kubernetes dependencies yaml file once a day for a newer chart version update?

For example:
My dependency file looks like that:

```
dependencies:
- name: kafka
  version: "15.4.0"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

After the schedule update it should open a new PR with the latest subcharts:

```
dependencies:
- name: kafka
  version: "20.0.2"
  repository: "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami"
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the tools to achieve this is Renovatebot. It has a Github Action (https://github.com/renovatebot/github-action) where you setup a cron job to create Pr's daily. You can modify its config file to add helm as a datasource. Here is a sample config

```
    {
      "fileMatch": ["xyz/values.yaml"],
      "matchStrings": [
        "chart:\n\\s*spec:\n\\s*version: \"(?<currentValue>.*?)\""
      ],
      "depNameTemplate": "ingress-nginx",
      "registryUrlTemplate": "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx",
      "datasourceTemplate": "helm"
    }
```